# How to access Flask Request header outside route method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to access headers for a certain API calls outside of its api route. I tried using the app_context and test_request_context but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask("app")

def access_header_for_something():
    with app.test_request_context():
        with app.app_context():
            print(request.headers.get("Authorization"), request.host, request.path)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    access_header_for_something()
    return 'hello'

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: Maybe you have to have aliases when using `with`, like `with something as this_thing: print(this_thing.attribute1)`

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet work with slight tweak:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask("app")

def access_header_for_something():
   with app.app_context():
      print(request.headers.get("Authorization"), request.host, request.path)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    access_header_for_something()
    return 'hello'

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Consider [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364) of what was changed specifically and why it solved the problem. This will help future readers to better understand your solution.